# C++ class Member pointer

Tags: c++

```
using namespace std;

class Line {
public:
    int getLength(void);
    Line(int len);
    ~Line();
    int *get();
    int *ptr;
};

int Line::getLength() {
    cout << *ptr << "\t";
    return *ptr;
}

Line::Line(int len) {
    ptr = &len;
    cout << *ptr << "\t";
    cout << ptr << "\t";
}


Line::~Line() {
    cout << "destroy";
}

int *Line::get() {
    return ptr;
}

int main() {
    Line line(10);
    cout << line.get() << "\t" << line.getLength() << "\t";
}
```

console out:

10      006FF82C        006FF82C        14245435        14245435        destroy

Why is this,
Why is the value in the ptr address not 10

Comment: `&len` is a pointer to the local argument `len`, whose scope is only the duration of the constructor. After the constructor returns, `len` is destroyed, and `&len` is a dangling pointer. Dereferencing it later when you call `getLength` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Within the scope of the constructor, *ptr does contain the value 10 but outside the scope of the constructor the value of ptr is undefined and depends on the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this

Because the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Within the constructor, `ptr` points to the parameter which has automatic storage. When the constructor returns, the storage duration of the parameter ends and the pointer becomes invalid. When you later indirect through the invalid pointer and attempt to access the memory, the behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It is 10, within the scope of your constructor, it's in the first 2 characters of your output. In your constructor

```
    Line::Line(int len) {
        ptr = &len;
        cout << *ptr << "\t";
        cout << ptr << "\t";
    }
```

The value '10' is stored in `int len`, then you store the address of len in ptr with `ptr = &len`, then you deference `ptr` with `cout << *ptr` to produce the value '10' in your output. Then it goes out of scope.

The rest of the output is the result of printing various address in calls to cout and return values from your functions.